# AzCopy (devops pipeline)is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PowerShell script that works all the time when I use from my local machine (I have azCopy installed):

```
AzCopy `
/Source:C:\myfolder `
/Dest:https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mystoragecontainer `
/DestKey:<storage-account-access-key> `
/Pattern:"myfile.txt"
```

Using azure pipeline (Microsoft Hosted agent) this script fails with

**"AzCopy.exe : The term 'AzCopy.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."**

I have tried different agents but still the same error.
Which agent I must use to use azCopy?

Am I missing the obvious?

Is there another way of doing this always using powershell?

Comment: Do you use Microsoft Hosted agent or Self hosted magnet?

Comment: I use Microsoft Hosted agent

Answer (score 1):

To copy files to Azure with AzCpoy you can use build-in task [Azure File Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy), you not need use PowerShell:

[image]

In addition, you can install the [Microsoft Azure Build and Release Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-azure) extension that give you another task "Azure Copy File Extended" with more options.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I cannot use the azure file copy task as require a service connection with full credentials in order to work.Hence I was using "Access Key".I have installed the extention too,but unless I am wrong it does require a service connectivity as well. Are we saying that unless we use the Azure File copy task it cannot be done? thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Shayki Abramczyk, the **Azcopy task** he provided can also be used to achieve copy file. This is another way, you can consider give it a try :-)

Back to this issue. According to error message, I think it's because the missing SDK in hosted agent.

Until now, Microsoft does not install **`Azure.Storage.AzCopy`** in every hosted agent. So, the agent you used may does not support this.

We provide [seven different agents](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation) for user use, but only [Hosted VS2017](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2017-Server2016-Readme.md), [Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/win/Vs2019-Server2019-Readme.md) and [Hosted Ubuntu 1604](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1604-) has been installed the SDK which support Azcopy.exe.

So, you can try with these three agents to execute your azcopy command with powershell.

**Edit**:

Becaues the executable file (**azcopy.exe**)is in local. So, where is your AzCopy.exe located? For me, it's `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy`.

So, in script, you need to execute `cd` command to change directory to the file where AzCopy.exe located first.

```
cd “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy”
```

**Note**: **DO** **NOT** lost **double quote** here, or you will get **x86 is not recognized**. If file path located not same with mine, just change file path with yours.

And then, because of using Powershell, you may need to use powershell syntax. Here is the complete format example which modify it based on your script:

```
$source="C:\MyFolder"
$dest="https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mystoragecontainer"
$pattern = "myfile.txt"
$destkey = <key>

cd “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\AzCopy”
$azcopy = .\AzCopy.exe /Source:$source /Dest:$dest /DestKey: $destkey 
/Pattern: $pattern
```

Please try with it.

Comment: Liang thanks for your reply. The AzCopy task just works that is not a problem but I need to do it using keys.I have tried all the agents and I get the same error in all of them.I copy my simple "Inline"script in my local machine command line and just works."AzCopy /Source:D:\MyFolder /Dest:https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mystoragecontainer /DestKey:myaccesskey /Pattern:"myfile.txt"  . Does not make sense. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: @developer9969, which task do you use? Powershell? Or Azure Powershell? The command of "azcopy.exe" can be executed in Azure Powershell on my side with Hosted VS2017.

Comment: liang thanks . Definitely doing something wrong then .I cannot use Azure Powershell as it requires "Service connectivity" using all the agents available. even added the capabilities "azurereps" and nothing

Comment: @developer9969 Hi, sorry for my misleading, I have update my answer with the way of execute azcopy command in powershell. Please try it. It’s worked on mine. Hope same with yours. Feel free to let me know the latest status of result.

Comment: Liang.Thanks for your reply.Really grateful for your time in replying.I CAN do it in a script since day one as x your example or using AzFileCopy task(ServiceConnection required). I need to do in a pipeline  . Can I execute that script in a pipeline ? Many thanks again

Comment: @developer9969 Of course it can, it’s work on my powershell task of build pipeline.

Comment: @developer9969 Does this script execute succeed on your powershell task? Feel free to let me know the latest status.

Comment: Note that while this _does_ work, the AzCopy installed in the image is v6.2.0, so unsupported.

Comment: @developer9969 Were you able to get this working? running azcopy in 2019 hosted agent?

Comment: @Darey yes I was able to make it work but not using the latest azcopy though , I have not looked into it since.

Comment: @developer9969 I was able to work it through by downloading the Azcopy Exe and setting the relevant directory for execution.

Answer (score 0):

For people like me, landing to this thread because they have this error by calling AZ copy in a PS Script, it's confirmed AZ Copy in not installed in Last (VM2019) version of Windows Hosted. But according to MS, binary is present in the Image, so you don't have to install it, but just to use the right path.
For more information about packages installed (or saved) on VM, you can check this [Git Repo](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win)